SQL Server query result is needed for an FCI server having multiple instances, I need the server name and not the cluster name
I need the server name on an FCI clustered server with multiple instances.  I can find cluster and ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS has the active nodes but cannot find the passive nodes.
I've found different queries that claim to answer my question but the do not.  On an FCI server that is controlled by Cluster, perhaps the servername is not available in SQL Server.
-- This give you the cluster not the server.
select isnull(
(select cluster_name from sys.dm_hadr_cluster),
@@SERVERNAME
)
From the different nodes I need to determine which is Active and which is Passive.  I can find the Active but not the Passive.
